# Is It Possible to Represent the Fractional Part of a Number as an Integer?

Tags: integers, sorting

This question may not even have an answer in mathematics, so I apologize if it is too dumb.

I am writing an algorithm to order a series of numbered items.  These items have a unique numbering style in which the decimal part of the number is treated as an integer and sorted accordingly.

For example, this is the correct order for the following items:

6, 6.1, 6.3, 6.10, 6.11, 6.30, 6.45, 7

In this example, the ".1" part is treated as the integer 1, which is less than the ".10" part, which translates to the integer 10.

I understand that this makes no sense from a standard mathematical point of view, since .10 is equivalent to .1, and 6.11 is normally less than 6.3.

Is there a mathematical notation that can treat the decimal part of a number as an integer?  Or is there a way of representing the "numbers" 6.11 and 6.3 in some numeric way that follows the required sorting style?  Sure, I can do something like set the maximum number of decimal places, and then translate ".1" to ".001", etc.  I'm just wondering if there is a more direct approach.

The standard math coding tools don't work with this data, because the numbers I am using really are not numbers at all; they are something else.  I can use string coding tools to sort these numbers correctly, but then I have to resort to special tricks to alphabetize the numbers correctly.

Comment: If you need to distinguish $3.1$ from $3.10$, then you will need to work with strings, not numbers. The string "$3.1$", which consists of the three characters '$3$', '$1$', and '$0$', is different from the string "$3.10$". It is probably a waste of time to try to convert these strings to numbers, unless you have a special reason for it.

Comment: I am currently using strings, because there is no way for the computer to distinguish 3.1 from 3.10 numerically.  Humans can easily do it, though, given the proper instructions!  It is really a multi-level sort: first the number is sorted by the integer portion, then it is sorted by the integer that follows the "."

Comment: My current implementation converts the string into an integer portion, and then sets a maximum decimal place level of 3, then converts the fractional portion (taken as an integer) into thousandths.  The sort works fine this way, but there is no way to make this function work for n undetermined decimal places.

Comment: So don't do it that way. Sort the string as a string directly. It will make for a good programming exercise.

Comment: Sorting as a string directly yields incorrect results: 6, 6.1, 6.10, 6.11, 6.3, 6.30, 6.45, 7.

Comment: By incorrect results do you mean it should be $6,6.1,6.3,6.10,6.11,6.30,6.45,7$?  A specific example like that would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is fixed-point arithmetic. Floating point decimals are more common, but fixed-point representation is often found in applications that involve digital signaling processors (DSPs).

The idea is similar to what others proposed - split the number to integer and decimal part. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string around the decimal point, then parse each part into an integer (there are library functions for this in most languages I've used) and sort by the first part and fall back to the second part to break ties.

Comment: This looks like the right way.  The numbers are being treated essentially like ordered pairs, with first element being treated as the higher-order element.